# Will i be blocked on sending large requests to any Site?

Tags: selenium, web

I have a task of translating documents from various languages to English . My approach to this problem was usage of Google translate .Since the API is quite expensive , i  decided to do it using Selenium .

As of now , I send around 500-1000 requests/day to translate.google.com via selenium . I am currently clearing cookies after translation of each and every document . Now my question is  if send such large requests to a site , is there any possibility of being blocked by such site ? If so , is there any other solution to this problem faced ?

Comment: Yes, this possibility does exist. Most providers of "free" services will at one point attempt to reduce the number of answers (in one way or another) given to an individual client. Are there possibilities to circumvent these measures? Maybe. Are you then breaking their TOS. Most likely.

Comment: "I want to do this manual and time-consuming task but I do not wish to pay for it. I've since found that I can freeload on another site and pass all/any costs onto them. How do I prevent them from stopping me?"

Comment: @reto : Do you have any suggestions / solution for this problem ? Would changing my IP address dynamically help anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to tweak Google why dont try another alternative which do allows large number of requests for free?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api